# Use yii2 for production

Tags: php, yii, yii2

it's about 6 months that the Yii2 preview (May 2013) was released. I think that in 6 months there are a lot bugs that were remove I would like to know it's a big risk for me to use yii2 for production. I would like to try my new project with Yii2. Are the people that use it for project with success? I understand that there are no extension at the moment. Most of time i dont use them !
thank for help))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's still risky to use yii2 for production, but there're some brave hearts who does it. For example I've heard [this site](https://www.theprintful.com/) is built with yii2. Also yii2 recently switched to php 5.4 and who knows what else will be changed. So, I would say it depends on your project requirements/strictness/complexity and time you're ready to spend for updating your code when something is changed in the framework. Also keep in mind that documentation isn't complete yet, and you'll have to look into source code quite often.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not a guru in PHP. It mean would not able to understand every line of code to change everything when they will upgrade the framework. think that it should be good for me to go for Yii1.1.14.

Comment: Yes, I think 1.1.14 would be good enough, especially if you're not quite familiar with framework yet. The 1.1 branch will be supported until 12/31/2015 or even further, so you can rely on it.

Comment: @rinat.io can you tell me what is the status of yii2 as of now, Can we start using yii2 in production?
PS I have good experience with yii1